# Selenium test stuck on starting using chromeDriver

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-chromedriver, fluentlenium

I am trying to write a selenium test with fluintlenium and for some reason when I try using the chrome driver it just open chrome on "data;" page and doesn't continue to the actual url I give it.
When I use HtmlUnitDriver it runs the test successfully but with chrome it just stuck after :

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 (****) on port 36888
>   Only local connections are allowed.

I know its just an information message but it doesnt continue after that just stuck it doesn't show any errors...

The code is:

```
public class IntegrationTest extends FluentTest {
public WebDriver driver;
@Override
public WebDriver getDefaultDriver() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    return driver;
}
/**
 * add your integration test here
 */
@Test
public void title_of_bing_should_contain_search_query_name() {
    goTo("http://www.bing.com");
    fill("#sb_form_q").with("FluentLenium");
    submit("#sb_form_go");
    assertThat(title()).contains("FluentLenium");
}
```

}

I tried using selenium's `driver.get("url");` but its not working either .

EDIT : How I run the tests? 1. I just start my selenium server 2. I use play so I run the command play test OR 2. I use eclipse junit test runner to run a single test.
Both doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean the chromedriver is not launched. It's just an information message that you can connect to it only locally.

If the browser opened and not doing anything further, in your case it means you have not compatible chrome and chrome driver. If your chrome is the latest one, then 2.13 chromedriver is too old for you, try 2.15

Comment: I am using the latest chrome and just updated the chrome driver but it still doesn't work ...

Comment: In your log I see you are using 2.13?

Comment: What selenium server version are you using? Is it running?

Comment: 2.44 
and its running

Comment: Ok, then it will be better if you will tell step by step how are you starting tests, and what are the steps you are performing (in the main question please)

Comment: there isnt much to say: 1. I just start my selenium server 2. I use play so I run the command play test OR 2. I use eclipse junit test runner to run a single test